# Meteor: Calling an asynchronous function inside a Meteor.method and returning the result

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to call an asynchronous function inside a Meteor method and then return the result from that function to Meteor.call.

(How) is that possible?

```
Meteor.methods({
  my_function: function(arg1, arg2) {
    //Call other asynchronous function and return result or throw error
  }
});
```

Comment: Topic updated for Meteor 0.8+ in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743402/how-to-get-an-async-data-in-a-function-with-meteor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Andrew Mao is right. Meteor now has [Meteor.wrapAsync()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync) for this kind of situation.

Here's the simplest way to do a charge via stripe and also pass a callback function:

```
var stripe = StripeAPI("key");    
Meteor.methods({

    yourMethod: function(callArg) {

        var charge = Meteor.wrapAsync(stripe.charges.create, stripe.charges);
        charge({
            amount: amount,
            currency: "usd",
            //I passed the stripe token in callArg
            card: callArg.stripeToken,
        }, function(err, charge) {
            if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
              // The card has been declined
              throw new Meteor.Error("stripe-charge-error", err.message);
            }

            //Insert your 'on success' code here

        });
    }
});
```

I found this post really helpful:
[Meteor: Proper use of Meteor.wrapAsync on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server)

Comment: if you return a value in the callback to charge() will that be the return of charge()?

Comment: Not clear where you're returning a value which is the point of the original question

Comment: This post is extremely helpful: https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/

Answer (score 36):

Use a Future to do so. Like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  my_function: function(arg1, arg2) {

    // Set up a future
    var fut = new Future();

    // This should work for any async method
    setTimeout(function() {

      // Return the results
      fut.ret(message + " (delayed for 3 seconds)");

    }, 3 * 1000);

    // Wait for async to finish before returning
    // the result
    return fut.wait();
  }
});
```

**Update**:

To use Future starting from Meteor 0.5.1, you have to run the following code in your Meteor.startup method:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require
  Future = require('fibers/future');

  // use Future here
});
```

**Update 2**:

To use Future starting from Meteor 0.6, you have to run the following code in your Meteor.startup method:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

  // use Future here
});
```

and then use the `return` method instead of the `ret` method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  my_function: function(arg1, arg2) {

    // Set up a future
    var fut = new Future();

    // This should work for any async method
    setTimeout(function() {

      // Return the results
      fut['return'](message + " (delayed for 3 seconds)");

    }, 3 * 1000);

    // Wait for async to finish before returning
    // the result
    return fut.wait();
  }
});
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joscha/4130605).

Comment: Thank you, Joscha. A future is exactly what I need.

Comment: @KONG, I updated my answer, see above. I also forked the initial gist to include that information: https://gist.github.com/4130605

Comment: @Joscha, Thanks a lot for your solution! I managed to google it myself. `Future` is such a common name for package :)

Comment: here's a full working demo of this: https://github.com/semateos/meteor-async-test

Comment: As of 0.6.0 you have to use `Future = Npm.require('fibers/future')`.

Comment: What if you want to do a Collection update/insert in the asynchronous callback?

Comment: @semateos I sent you a pull req on the demo, because it does not work with post 0.6 any more

Comment: For me, what works is Future = Meteor.require('fibers/future').

Comment: `fut.return(result)` works for me; why not follow [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399)?

Answer (score 26):

Recent versions of Meteor have provided the undocumented `Meteor._wrapAsync` function which turns a function with a standard `(err, res)` callback into a synchronous function, meaning that the current Fiber yields until the callback returns, and then uses Meteor.bindEnvironment to ensure that you retain the current Meteor environment variables (such as `Meteor.userId())`.

A simple use would be as the following:

```
asyncFunc = function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
  // callback has the form function (err, res) {}

};

Meteor.methods({
  "callFunc": function() {
     syncFunc = Meteor._wrapAsync(asyncFunc);

     res = syncFunc("foo", "bar"); // Errors will be thrown     
  }
});
```

You may also need to use `function#bind` to make sure that `asyncFunc` is called with the right context before wrapping it.

For more information see: https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/meteor-meteor-wrapasync

Comment: as of 0.9.3 _wrapAsync has been deprecated in favor of wrapAsync https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/50e6d3143db8fc6e1fc3fb74da74b40c8dc7f3a4/packages/meteor/helpers.js#L153

Answer (score 5):

Another option is this [package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-async) which achieves the similar goals.

```
meteor add meteorhacks:async
```

From the package README:

**Async.wrap(function)**

*Wrap an asynchronous function and allow it to be run inside Meteor without callbacks.*

```
//declare a simple async function
function delayedMessge(delay, message, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, message);
  }, delay);
}

//wrapping
var wrappedDelayedMessage = Async.wrap(delayedMessge);

//usage
Meteor.methods({
  'delayedEcho': function(message) {
    var response = wrappedDelayedMessage(500, message);
    return response;
  }
});
```