# MeteorJS async code inside synchronous Meteor.methods function

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to get the client method.call to wait for an asynchronous function to finish? Currently it reaches the end of the function and returns undefined.

Client.js

```
Meteor.call( 'openSession', sid, function( err, res ) {
    // Return undefined undefined
    console.log( err, res ); 
});
```

Server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    openSession: function( session_id ) {
        util.post('OpenSession', {session: session_id, reset: false }, function( err, res ){
            // return value here with callback?
            session_key = res;
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to perform asynchronous tasks inside meteor methods from the client. In the server using Fiber could be an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recent versions of Meteor have provided the undocumented `Meteor._wrapAsync` function which turns a function with a standard `(err, res)` callback into a synchronous function, meaning that the current Fiber yields until the callback returns, and then uses Meteor.bindEnvironment to ensure that you retain the current Meteor environment variables (such as `Meteor.userId())`.

A simple use would be as the following:

```
asyncFunc = function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
  // callback has the form function (err, res) {}

};

Meteor.methods({
  "callFunc": function() {
     syncFunc = Meteor._wrapAsync(asyncFunc);

     res = syncFunc("foo", "bar"); // Errors will be thrown     
  }
});
```

You may also need to use `function#bind` to make sure that `asyncFunc` is called with the right context before wrapping it.
For more information see: https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/meteor-meteor-wrapasync

Answer (score 6):

I was able to find the answer in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/3443021). In order to run asynchronous code from within a method.call you use Futures which forces your function to wait.

```
    var fut = new Future();
    asyncfunc( data, function( err, res ){
        fut.ret( res );
    });
    return fut.wait();
```

Comment: I was going to suggest future/promise but didn't realize that it's built into Meteor. Useful all over the place.

Comment: You are a straight G. This is some shot caller level code right here

Comment: Futures is no longer part of Meteor core, so this no longer works.

Comment: @iiz Sure it is. `var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');`

Answer (score 0):

Update: Sorry, I should have read the question more carefully. It looks like this question was also asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569712/meteor-calling-an-asynchronous-function-inside-a-meteor-method-and-returning-th).

Apart from futures, another pattern to consider might be updating another model with the data returned from the asynchronous call and then subscribing to that model's changes.

---

From the [meteor.call documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) it looks like the the result argument `(err, res)` of your callback function should contain the output of your openSession function. But you aren't returning any values from your openSession function so the return value is undefined.

You can test this:

Client:

```
Meteor.call('foo', function(err, res) {
  console.log(res); // undefined
});

Meteor.call('bar', function(err, res) {
  console.log(res); // 'bar'
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  foo: function() {
    var foo = 'foo';
  },
  bar: function() {
    var bar = 'bar';
    return bar;
  }
});
```