# Meteor method not returning error or result value

Tags: meteor

Here is my server side code

```
Meteor.methods({
   addSupportRequest: function (support) {
    Support.insert(support, function (err, id) {
        if (err)
            throw new Meteor.Error(404, "Oops! Network Error. Please submit help request again. ");

            console.log("Support resuest added: " + id);
           return id;

    });
} // End addSupportRequest
```

});

Here is the client side code

```
App.Util = {
call: function (method, params, callback) {
    NProgress.start();
    Meteor.apply(method, params, function (error, result) {
        NProgress.done();

       console.log(error);
        console.log(result);
        callback(error, result);

    });
} // end Call
```

};

Please help me find out why meteor method call is not returning error or result. console.log() showing new record Id on server but showing undefined on client.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that is preventing your method from returning a result is that `return id;` is in the function scope of the insert callback, and not the scope of the meteor method. So it will return from the callback and then there is no return in the meteor method function which is implicitly a `return undefined`.

You should add a return to the method's scope like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
   addSupportRequest: function (support) {
    return Support.insert(support, function (err, id) {
        if (err)
            throw new Meteor.Error(404, "Oops! Network Error. Please submit help request again. ");

            console.log("Support resuest added: " + id);
           return id;

    });
} // End addSupportRequest
```

As for the error, I am not sure why it isn't surfacing as it should traverse up the call stack (doesn't matter that it is inside an inner function like the return) and since it is a Meteor.Error it should get sent to the client as well.

Answer (score 1):

Dsyko's answer was somewhat on the right track. However, the asynchronous callback will never pass its result to the scope of the original function, which has ended.

What you want is to run the `Support.insert` operation **synchronously**, i.e. having the current fiber yield while I/O is happening. This is what the [`Meteor._wrapAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542354/586086) function is for. Luckily for you, there is no need to do this manually because if you just take out the callback from the insert operation, it will run synchronously:

```
Meteor.methods({
   addSupportRequest: function (support) {
     var id = Support.insert(support);
     // An error may be thrown here, but it certainly won't be a network error because the request will have already reached the server.
     console.log("Support request added: " + id);
     return id;
   });
}
```