# Meteor: Proper use of Meteor.wrapAsync on server

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments

**Background**

I'm trying to integrate stripe payments into my site. I need to create a stripe user using my private stripe key. I'm storing this key on my server, and calling a server method to create the user. Maybe there's another way of accomplishing this? Here's the stripe api (copied below for convenience):
https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer

```
//stripe api call
var Stripe = StripeAPI('my_secret_key');

Stripe.customers.create({
  description: 'Customer for test@example.com',
  card: "foobar" // obtained with Stripe.js
}, function(err, customer) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

**My attempts and results**

I've been using the same client code with different server code. All attempts immediately give undefined on the client's console.log(...) but give the proper response on the server console.log(...):

```
//client
Meteor.call('stripeCreateUser', options, function(err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
});

//server attempt 1
var Stripe = StripeAPI('my_secret_key');

Meteor.methods({
    stripeCreateUser: function(options) {  
        return Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.customers.create({
            description: 'Woot! A new customer!',
            card: options.ccToken,
            plan: options.pricingPlan
        }, function (err, res) {
            console.log(res, err);
            return (res || err);
        }));
    }
});

//server attempt 2
var Stripe = StripeAPI('my_secret_key');

Meteor.methods({
    stripeCreateUser: function(options) {  
        return Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.customers.create({
            description: 'Woot! A new customer!',
            card: options.ccToken,
            plan: options.pricingPlan
        }));
    }
});
```

I've also tried both without Meteor.wrapAsync.

EDIT - I'm also using this package:
https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe

Comment: oh hey, googled this question and it's nearly identical to my code

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From the `Meteor.wrapAsync` http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_wrapasync you can see that you need to pass it a function and optionally a context, whereas on your two attempts you are passing the RESULT of calling the async version of `Stripe.customers.create`.

```
Meteor.methods({
  stripeCreateUser: function(options) {
    // get a sync version of our API async func
    var stripeCustomersCreateSync=Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.customers.create,Stripe.customers);
    // call the sync version of our API func with the parameters from the method call
    var result=stripeCustomersCreateSync({
      description: 'Woot! A new customer!',
      card: options.ccToken,
      plan: options.pricingPlan
    });
    // do whatever you want with the result
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

`Meteor.wrapAsync` transforms an async function into a convenient synchronous-looking function which allows to write sequentially looking code. (underhood everything is still executed within the asynchronous Node.js event loop).

We need to pass to `Meteor.wrapAsync` our API function (`Stripe.customers.create`) along with the function context, ie `this` inside the body of the API func, which in this case is `Stripe.customers`.

EDIT :

> How to retrieve errors ?

Traditional node style API functions usually take a callback as last argument that will get called ultimately when the required task is completed. This callback takes 2 arguments : error and data, either one will be null according to the result of the call.

How do we access the error object using the synchronous wrapped functions returned by `Meteor.wrapAsync` ?

We have to rely on using try/catch blocks, because in case of error, it will be thrown by the sync function instead of being passed as first argument of the async function callback.

```
try{
  var result=syncFunction(params);
  console.log("result :",result);
}
catch(error){
  console.log("error",error);
}
// is the equivalent of :
asyncFunc(params,function(error,result){
  if(error){
    console.log("error",error);
    return;
  }
  console.log("result :",result);
});
```

> why doesn't Stripe need to be passed?

JavaScript has no "namespace" concept, so API developers use the common trick of defining a global object acting as API namespace, properties defined on this object are "sub-modules" of the API.
It means that `Stripe.customers` is a submodule of the Stripe API exposing customers-related funcs, and as such these funcs `this` context is `Stripe.customers`, not `Stripe`.

You can test it yourself by copy pasting this mocking code in your browser console :

```
Stripe={
  customers:{
    create:function(){
      console.log(this==Stripe.customers);
    }
  }
};
```

And then calling the stub function in your browser console like this :

```
> Stripe.customers.create();
true
```

Comment: Thanks. The documentation wasn't as clear to me as your answer.

I also don't completely comprehend your last paragraph. I'll have to study that bit a little bit more. For example, why doesn't Stripe need to be passed?

Thanks again!

Comment: how do you get an error? I saw elsewhere you can still provide a callback that will receive (error, data), but in the synchronous response will an error object be there instead of data if it failed?

Comment: This is addressed in my latest edit, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @saimeunt How do you get the error back to the client if you use Meteor.call from the client? If you set a callback on the client (you have to if you don't use a stub) there appears to be no way of returning traditional-style (err, result) only result can be returned. Any light on this would be gratefully received.

Comment: @saimeunt I seem to have solved my particular problem of sending the error back. I'll put it as an answer if anybody is interested

Comment: @saimeunt yes please share how to sent the data, error back to the client.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Stripe.charges.create, I have followed what you suggest but I want to send a value back to client side method call, this could be the error and result. I have posted my issuere here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167076/returning-stripe-charge-result-to-client-in-meteor

Comment: For anyone else who has trouble getting the import syntax right in Meteor 1.3 or overlooks where secret key needs to be passed, this is what worked for me: var Stripe = require("stripe")(Meteor.settings.stripe.secretKey);

Answer (score 11):

Another option is this [package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-async) which achieves the similar goals.

```
meteor add meteorhacks:async
```

From the package README:

**Async.wrap(function)**

*Wrap an asynchronous function and allow it to be run inside Meteor without callbacks.*

```
//declare a simple async function
function delayedMessge(delay, message, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, message);
  }, delay);
}

//wrapping
var wrappedDelayedMessage = Async.wrap(delayedMessge);

//usage
Meteor.methods({
  'delayedEcho': function(message) {
    var response = wrappedDelayedMessage(500, message);
    return response;
  }
});
```

Comment: Huh, I wonder about wrapping a Meteor.call method itself. Meteor.call is supposed to have a callback when called from the client. So maybe we could wrap that method.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Note that Meteor callbacks are asynchronous. See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call

Comment: Ok, so for sync method calls don't give it a callback

Answer (score 7):

First of all, thanks to @saimeunt for his answer, which makes some difficult concepts clear.
However I had the problem of wanting a classic async callback(err, result) showing both the error and the result back on the client, so that I can give informative messages in the browser.

I solved it this way:

Server code:

```
var Stripe = StripeAPI(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

Meteor.methods({
    createCust: Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.charges.create, Stripe.charges)
});
```

Client code:

```
var stripeCallOptions = {
    description: 'Woot! A new customer!',
    card: ccToken,
    plan: pricingPlan
};


Meteor.call('createCust', stripeCallOptions, function(error, result){
    console.log('client error', error);
    console.log('client result', result);
});
```

Looks neat. However unfortunately wrapAsync has an open bug, (see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2774) because it doesn't restore the proper error to the caller. A genius called Faceyspacey has written a replacement called Meteor.makeAsync() which you will find on the bug page I mentioned, which however returns either the result OR the error to the 'result' variable, leaving the 'error' variable undefined. 
That's fine by me for now, at least I've got a hook on the proper error object.

If you use makeAsync() you will need to import Futures like this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    //this is so that our makeAsync function works
    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to need almost every function to be wraped in Async what you should do is use this package `https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/stripe-sync` it prewraps all stripe functions with WrapAsync making your life easier and code cleaner.

Comment: life easier and code cleaner .. you shouldn't assume he has a dirty life :p