# How to handle errors on Meteor.wrapAsync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, easypost

I have a meteor method where I am using the easy post api. Below is some asyncronous code which I expect to give an error from the EasyPost api (because it is an invalid address).

```
EasyPost = Easypost("<you don't get to see my api key>");
EasyPost.Address.create_and_verify(address, function (err, response) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

This gives me the following response, which is what I expect.

```
{
  message: {
    code: "ADDRESS.VERIFY.FAILURE",
    message: "Address Not Found",
    errors: []
  },
  param: undefined
}
```

I want to try and make this syncronous, so I tried the following, but my `meteor shell` always logs `[Object object]`

```
> var createAndVerifySync = Meteor.wrapAsync(EasyPost.Address.create_and_verify, EasyPost.Address);
> createAndVerifySync(address);
[object Object]
```

I suspect this has to do with the error message from EasyPost returning as an object. How could I create a wrapper around the asyncronous methods of `EasyPost` with the inclusion of Meteor and futures?

Comment: See this post, which is all about the problems with returning errors from Meteor.wrapAsync. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server/29602309#29602309 There's an open bug, and I ended up using a bit of a hack.

Comment: If my answer was useful, it would be great if you would go back to the question in the link and upvote my answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For future travelers, this was answered via [this comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381876/how-to-handle-errors-on-meteor-wrapasync#comment48858029_30381876) by @mwarren on this question.