# Meteor.wrapAsync() not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I'm following a guide over at [The Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/) to wrap an asynchronous function and call it synchronously. However, when the code executes it appears to just jump over the method call entirely. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
if (!err) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'ldapLogin': function(username, password) {
      var syncFunc = Meteor.wrapAsync(processLdapLogin);
      var result = syncFunc(username, password, Meteor.user());

      console.log(result);
    }
  });
  Meteor.call('ldapLogin', username, password);
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `processLdapLoginWrapAsync()` from? All you did was declare a Meteor method, you have to call it in order for it to work.

Comment: Hmm, this is what I was wondering, but none of the multiple guides I've read online actually show calling the newly created method...

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a need to put it in a Meteor method at all. Remove lines 2,3,8,9 and see how that goes. [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server)

Comment: what kind of error do you see?

Comment: I've changed my original post to include the suggestions from the answers/comments and am now getting the following error on line 2 above: `Error invoking Method 'ldapLogin': Method not found [404]`

Answer (score 0):

Meteor `Methods` go on the server side

`Meteor.call("ldapLogin", username, password, Meteor.user());` calls goes on the Client side (web browser side)

Now, if you are passing parameters in your client side code (username, password...), you should also reference those in your method:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'processLdapLoginWrapAsync': function(username, password) {
      var syncFunc = Meteor.wrapAsync(processLdapLogin);
      var result = syncFunc(username, password, Meteor.user());

      console.log(result);
    }
  });
```

(if indeed this is intended from the client of course)

otherwise (if the username/password come from the server side, which I believe is really what you intended here) you should not be passing those parameters from the client and only call:

`Meteor.call("ldapLogin")`
on the client