# How can I execute a callback on a meteor method that does async calls?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, methods, callback

My client is making a call to the server.

```
Meteor.call('someRequest', params, onAllDoneCallback);
```

that is processed by (server code)

```
Meteor.methods({
    'someRequest': function(params, cb) {
        anAsyncFunction(params, cb);
        return true;
    },
});
```

I'd like the `onAllDoneCallback` to be triggered on the client side once the `anAsyncFunction` has finished and triggers its own callback.

However, in Meteor it seems that the second argument of `someRequest` is ignored and that the `onAllDoneCallback` is triggered with what `someRequest` returns, which here is `true` and which is called before that `anAsyncFunction` has finished.

In my case I'm more concerned about the timing issue (I'm using it to tell the client that the processing is finished, and not just that the request is well received) but other will probably want to call the callback with arguments from `anAsyncFunction`

Comment: you should return your result in the callback instead of returning True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing now is passing a function to the server. If that *does* work, it's very insecure. What you want to do is create a future and then use it to manage the asynchronous function. Here is an example:

```
let Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
Meteor.methods({
  someRequest: function (someArg) {
    // for security reasons, make sure you check the type of arguments.
    check(someArg, String);

    // future is an async handler.
    let future = new Future();
    // this is a function for a generic node style callback [ie, function (err, res)]
    let resolver = future.resolver();

    // run your function and pass it the future resolver
    // the future will be resolved when the callback happens.
    anAsyncFunction(someArg, resolver);

    // this meteor method will not end until future has been resolved.
    return future.wait();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, Meteor provides a `wrapAsync` that provides similar functionality of wrapping async functions in futures so they can run in meteor methods. That is:

```
let wrappedAsyncFunction = Meteor.wrapAsync(anAsyncFunction /** second argument is `this` binding*/);
return wrappedAsyncFunction();
```

Comment: I had just found about it! What's your take on `future` vs `wrapAsync`? https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/#tmc-using-wrapasync seems to recommend `wrapAsync` as a good default

Comment: If you need more granular control over the "flow" of execution, it's _very_ beneficial to know how futures work. For example, if you are using an `EventEmitter` and need to unbind listeners after resolving. [This guide](https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021) has been a life-saver for me when using meteor's future wrappings, good to keep with you

Comment: Best example on using futures for async methods I found!

Answer (score 0):

adapting this answer: [Meteor: Proper use of Meteor.wrapAsync on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server)

You have to use `Meteor`'s `wrapAsync` [api](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync), which takes a function that accepts a callback as its last argument, the callback being like `function(error, result){}`. So it will look like:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'someRequest': function(params){
        var wrap = Meteor.wrapAsync(anAsyncFunction);
        return wrap(params);
    },
});
```