# How to return async result from a method?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, callback

I am trying to return a value from a `Meteor.method` returned by an async callback function, like so:

```
Meteor.method('myMethod', () => {
    asyncFunction(result => {
        // Meteor.method should return this result
    });
});
```

Where should I put the `return result;` statement?

Comment: Checkout this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
Meteor.method('myMethod', () => {
    return asyncFunction(result => {
        // Meteor.method should return this result
return result;
    });
});
```