# Meteor DDP Callback inside a Method callback

Tags: meteor

This Meteor server code makes a DDP call to external service `serv2` and once it gets the result, it suppose to send back to the client which made the call, but it is not.

What is the best fix? Should I take advantage of MongoDB reactiveness?

```
/////////////////////////// client/main.js \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    Meteor.call('service2', function (err, res) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('got it');  //=> prints right away without waiting.
        console.log(res);       //=> print undefined <==================
        instance.msg.set(res);
      }
    });
  }
});

/////////////////////////// server/app.js \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { DDP } from 'meteor/ddp-client';

let serv2 = DDP.connect('localhost:7001');

Meteor.methods({
  'service2': function () {
    serv2.call('service2', function (err, res) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(res); //=> prints OK
        return 'service 1 calling service 2 <br> + res'; //<====== failed to return.
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what is happening:

- Client calls the `service2` method on the server and waits for a DDP response before calling the callback.
- The server starts to run the `service2` function in which your `serv2.call()` line *initiates* the .call() to your :7001 server.
- `serv2.call()` immediately returns, since the call is asynchronous.
- The `service2` function is now complete, and returns `undefined` since it does not have any return statement.
- Your client callback gets this result and runs as you described.
- At some later point the call to serv2 is complete, and it's callback is run, but since no one is listening to its return value it is lost in the void...

To make your setup work you need to make `service2()` wait for the result of `serv2.call()`. The method `Meteor.wrapAsync()` exists for this purpose. See http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync.

You might also benefit from the discussion here: [Meteor: Proper use of Meteor.wrapAsync on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server)