# Meteor run within a Fiber with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this error when I tried use sleep for a loop

> Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.

My Code:

```
   fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error get file");
      }

       if(files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i <files.length; i++) {
          Fiber(function()
          { 
            setTimeout( function()
            {
              Meteor.call('mymethodfile', files[i]);
            }, 1000 );
          }).run();
        }
      }
    });
```

in the same file

```
Meteor.methods({
    'mymethodfile':function(arch)
    {
      var file=arch;
      console.log(file);
      getdata(file);
    }
})
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap an asynchronous function, you should you `Meteor async wrap` method or `meteorhacks:async` package, you can see the related answer here: [Meteor: Proper use of Meteor.wrapAsync on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226583/meteor-proper-use-of-meteor-wrapasync-on-server)

If you want to use setTimeout, you have to use `Meteor.setTimeout` method instead: https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html