# Asynchronous function with multiple emit events (futures in meteor)

Tags: node.js, meteor, future

My use case is to read RSS feed items asynchronously and load them into a meteor collection.

I have the feedparser npm module that does the parsing. It emits three events .on('error'), .on('meta') and .on('readable) with three different outputs.

When I run it in fixtures.js, with just console.log statements to run the output, its working fine.
When I use the same code to insert into a collection, I get errors related to asynchronocity of the function (assuming something to do with fibers)

So, I want to make it into a meteor method using futures as below - 
http://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399

I tried but could not wrap my head around handling multiple events in Futures.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to push something to db at one point, it's enough to synchronize this call. Other than that, you can do whatever you want asynchronously. For example:

```
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
var item = {};

var onInit = function() {
    // do whatever with item
};

var onData = function() {
    // do whatever with item
};

var onFinish = function() {
    new Fiber(function(){
        Documents.insert(item);
    }).run();
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Although Meteor is a great tool, I think node and its async insight is brilliant, and the best tool for what you are doing.  Keep as a plan b having this part of your project be a straight node app.

Otherwise,
[async from meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269507/how-to-call-async-method-from-meteor-own-callbacks)
[and](https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021)