# Meteor.methods: return data to client from internal callbacks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor

I try to get data from an LDAP-Server via a Meteor server to the client. 
But the LDAP-Request is asynchronous and the method returns false and not the result that is collected in the ldap.search function-call. So, how can i get the calls to the ldap synchronously or trigger an event on the client when the data is ready?

```
  //defined on serverside
  Meteor.methods({
    searchPerson: function(account){
      var data = null;
      var LDAP = Npm.require('LDAP');
      var ldap = new LDAP({uri: 'ldaps://ldap-server', version: 3});

      var search_options = { 
        base: 'ou=xxx,dc=yyy,dc=zzz',
        scope: '1',
        filter: '(uid='+account+')',
        attrs: 'surname, givenname, mail'
      };  
      var bind_options = { 
        binddn:   'cn=aaa,ou=bbb,dc=ccc,dc=ddd', 
        password: 'password'
      };  

      ldap.open(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          throw new Meteor.Error('Can not connect');
        }   
        ldap.simpleBind(bind_options, function(err){
          if (err){
            throw new Meteor.Error('Can not bind');
          }   
          ldap.search(search_options, function(err, data){
            if (err){
              throw new Meteor.Error('Error occured');
            }   
            return data;
          }); 
        }); 
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Thanks a lot.

torrofs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is Meteor futures, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569712/meteor-calling-an-asynchronous-function-inside-a-meteor-method-and-returning-th). [This gist](https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021) explains how.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at that answer. It's exactly what i am looking for.