# Working with Meteor and Async balanced-payments functions

Tags: meteor, balanced-payments

I'm using balanced-payments and their version 1.1 of balanced.js within Meteor.

I'm trying to create a new customer using 
`balanced.marketplace.customers.create(formData);`

Here is my CheckFormSubmitEvents.js file

```
Template.CheckFormSubmit.events({
    'submit form': function (e, tmpl) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var recurringStatus = $(e.target).find('[name=is_recurring]').is(':checked');
        var checkForm = {
            name: $(e.target).find('[name=name]').val(),
            account_number: $(e.target).find('[name=account_number]').val(),
            routing_number: $(e.target).find('[name=routing_number]').val(),
            recurring: { is_recurring: recurringStatus },
            created_at: new Date
        }
        checkForm._id = Donations.insert(checkForm);

            Meteor.call("balancedCardCreate", checkForm, function(error, result) {
                console.log(result);
                // Successful tokenization
            if(result.status_code === 201 && result.href) {
                // Send to your backend
                jQuery.post(responseTarget, {
                    uri: result.href
                }, function(r) {
                    // Check your backend result
                    if(r.status === 201) {
                        // Your successful logic here from backend
                    } else {
                        // Your failure logic here from backend
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // Failed to tokenize, your error logic here
            }

            // Debuging, just displays the tokenization result in a pretty div
            $('#response .panel-body pre').html(JSON.stringify(result, false, 4));
            $('#response').slideDown(300);
            });
      }
});
```

Here is my Methods.js file

```
var wrappedDelayedFunction = Async.wrap(balanced.marketplace.customers.create);

Meteor.methods({
    balancedCardCreate: function (formData) {
        console.log(formData);
        var response =  wrappedDelayedFunction(formData);
        console.log(response);
        return response;    
    }
});
```

I get nothing back when I submit the form, except that on the server console I do see the log of the form data.

I'm sure I'm not calling some of these async functions correctly. The hard part for me here is that the balanced function are async, but I don't know if they fit into the same mold as some of the examples I've seen.

I've tried to follow this example code. 
http://meteorhacks.com/improved-async-utilities-in-meteor-npm.html

Is there a specific change that needs to be done in regard to working with balanced here? Does anyone have any tips for working with Async functions or see something specific about my code that I've done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using a future. This works great, I just need to do better at catching errors. Which will be a question for a pro I think   ; - )

Credit should go to user3374348 for answering another similar question of mine, which solved both of these. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23777507/582309

```
    var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");

      function extractFromPromise(promise) {
        var fut = new Future();
        promise.then(function (result) {
          fut["return"](result);
        }, function (error) {
          fut["throw"](error);
        });
        return fut.wait();
      }

    Meteor.methods({
      createCustomer: function (data) {
      balanced.configure(Meteor.settings.balancedPaymentsAPI);

      var customerData =  extractFromPromise(balanced.marketplace.customers.create({
        'name': data.fname + " " + data.lname,
        "address": {
          "city": data.city,
          "state": data.region,
          "line1": data.address_line1,
          "line2": data.address_line2,
          "postal_code": data.postal_code,
        },
        'email': data.email_address, 
        'phone': data.phone_number
        }));
var card = extractFromPromise(balanced.marketplace.cards.create({
          'number': data.card_number,
          'expiration_year': data.expiry_year,
          'expiration_month': data.expiry_month,
          'cvv': data.cvv
        }));
          var associate = extractFromPromise(card.associate_to_customer(customerData.href).debit({
          "amount": data.total_amount*100,
          "appears_on_statement_as": "Trash Mountain" })); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The NPM utilities `Async.wrap` does the same thing as the undocumented Meteor function `Meteor._wrapAsync`, in that it takes an asynchronous function with the last argument `function(err, result) {}` and turns it into a synchronous function which takes the same arguments, but either returns a result or throws an error instead of using the callback. The function yields in a Fiber until the asynchronous callback returns, so that other code in the event loop can run.

One pitfall with this is that you need to make sure that the function you wrap is called with the correct context. So if `balanced.marketplace.customers.create` is a prototype method that expects `this` to be set to something, it will not be set properly unless you bind it yourself, using `function.bind` or any of the other various library polyfills.

For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542356/586086.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew mentioned, you need to set the context for the method.

Here's the way you can do that with `Async.wrap`

```
Async.wrap(balanced.marketplace.customers, "create");
```

Comment: When I use this the function never seems to return from the server call. It is like the async function is not passing on to the next step

Comment: Okay, balanced has a promise API. This does not work then. You need to use futures directly or Async.runSync

Comment: Ok, do I still need to set the context for the method before running Async.runSync? Do you have more examples of Aysnc.runSync? I'm trying to use it now, but I'm getting undefined data, I still don't believe I have it setup correctly.