# How to use Mongo Collection methods when using Q?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, promise, q

I wish to update a Mongo collection in some code that looks like this:

```
var Q = Npm.require('q');
var db = new Mongo.Collection('mydb');

function doSomething() {
    var d = Q.defer();
    setTimeout( function() {
        d.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    return d.promise;
}

doSomething().then( function() {
    console.log('before find');
    var records = db.find({}).fetch(); // blocking operation never completes
    console.log('after find');
    console.log(records); // should be []
});
```

When running meteor with the above code, it will get as far as logging "before find" but then the execution is halted waiting for `db.find` to complete. It never completes.

Are there any solutions or workarounds for this?

Update: it seems to be the `.fetch()` that causes the issue. I need this part though, I want to manipulate the data I am receiving from Mongo.

Comment: Using promises in meteor server code is not really idiomatic. If you're using an npm package which exports promises, extract them synchronously using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773057/a/23777507 . Otherwise you could try wrapping your `then` callback in `Meteor.bindEnvironment`, as in `.then(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {...}))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using fetch, add a callback function. 
It will allow you to manipulate the data after its retrieved:

```
var records = db.find({}, function(error, data){

        // Do something with your data here
});
```

** Edit - with the callback above, a curser is returned. If you want to return an Array with the results, use the following:

```
 var records = db.find({}).toArray(function(error, data){

        // Do something with your data here
});
```