# How to connect meteor server to another tcp server via tcp socket

Tags: tcp, meteor, client

I want to create a meteor application that connect meteor server to another tcp server,
that is meteor server is client side and another tcp server is server side.

1.It like WebSocket of browser ,but I want use it on meteor server ,not on meteor client .
WebSocket using like :

```
  var tcpServer = "ws://some.tcpServer.org/";
  socket = new WebSocket(tcpServer,options); 
  socket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
  socket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) }; 
  socket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
  socket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
```

2.Maybe as follow :

```
  if (Meteor.isServer) {  
    Meteor.startup(function () {
      var tcpServer = "ws://some.tcpServer.org/";
      socket = new socketClient(tcpServer,options); 
      socket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt) };
      socket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt) }; 
      socket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt) };
      socket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt) };
    })
  }
```

3.Or ...

```
  var net = Npm.require('net');
  net.createServer(function(socket){...} is for server side , not fit for my idea.
  Maybe like net.createClient(function(tcpServer, options ){...} , but no this method.
```

I had been looking around but i do not see a method for Meteor. Can anyone give any pointers for me to start?

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with what you described.

[WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), which works over HTTP, and [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) are completely different protocols. You will not be able to open a WebSocket connection to a TCP server.

To have the Meteor server communicate with another server over TCP, you'll want to use Node's [net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) API. To use this with Meteor, you'll need to use async callbacks in a way that is compatible with Fibers; see [this blog post](http://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html) for an overview and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21542356/586086.

Comment: Thank your answer, It is helpful for me. Let me knew about it clearly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have link to working plugin:

[websocketify on atmosphere.com](https://atmospherejs.com/jakozaur/websockify)