# Callback in client for Meteor method call returning undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I'm calling a method from the client that has a callback:

```
Meteor.call("readHeaders", Meteor.user().emails[0].address+'/'+Session.get("file1"), 
            function(err,result){
                console.log(result);
        });
```

and here is the method that's being called:

```
readHeaders: function(fileName){
        var nodeFS = Meteor.npmRequire('node-fs');
        nodeFS.readFile("somepath/"+fileName,'utf8', function read(err, data){
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var headers = [data.slice(0,data.indexOf('\n')).split(",")];

            return headers;

        });
    }
```

The correct result gets printed on the server, but on the client it returns undefined. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried logging the err in console on client to see what it is? You might need to use Meteor.bindEnvironment on the readFile callback since you are making an async call to an external node library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569712/meteor-calling-an-asynchronous-function-inside-a-meteor-method-and-returning-th/21542356#21542356

Comment: @BrianShamblen He's got a callback, this doesn't appear to be an issue of asynchronocity.

Comment: You're returning the headers value inside the callback of the fs function. At that point the meteor method has already returned. Look into fibers or wrapAsync.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your method call and callback are fine, but your method itself is probably not returning what you're expecting. Add a `console.log(headers)` before the `return headers` line and make sure it's an object.