# Return json from method in meteor even after using setTimeout

Tags: json, meteor

I am creating method which saves customer in database and return response in json format back to calling method. Here is my Code:

```
    Meteor.methods({
    'Registration': function() {
    name = "Hardik";
    contact = "";
    email = "admin@gmail.com";
    password = "123";
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {liveDb.db.query('Insert Into Customer (Customer_Name, Customer_Contact, Customer_Password, Customer_Email) values ("'+name+'","'+contact+'","'+password+'","'+email+'")',
        function(error, result){
            if(result!='undefined' && result.affectedRows>0)
            {
                var r = {message : "Customer Added Successfully.", statuscode: "200", customerid : result.insertId};
                return r;
            }
            else
            {
                var r = {message : "Something Went Wrong", statuscode: "400", error : error};
                return r;
            }   
        });},1000);
    }
});
```

But when I try to fetch returned value in client I am getting nothing
Client Side Code:

```
Meteor.call('Registration', function (error, result) {
        console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I think, Your call is Async, so you will get response after a while, Also you are returning from callback method, not from original method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor: Calling an asynchronous function inside a Meteor.method and returning the result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569712/meteor-calling-an-asynchronous-function-inside-a-meteor-method-and-returning-th)

Comment: It might be possible because of async. let me check it

Comment: so even after using setTimeout, I am facing same issue

Comment: Can you explain what the timeout is for?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to return response from async callback.

Answer to this question is already give here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587886/1625793